# How would I convert numbers to their decimal representation?

Tags: hex, decimal

I am not sure how to approach it but could someone help me convert the  following   numbers to  their   decimal representation:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I hope I could convince that I really need help in this :(

Comment: 456(7) is 4*7*7+5*7+6. You should be able to derive a more general rule, and then an algorithm.

Comment: C'mon. Did you go to school yet?

Comment: Thanks Didierc, So it'd be 237, right?

Comment: PM 77-1, no actually. Can we not judge please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general method goes something like this:

Work from right to left, you'll want to count the positions (starting with zero) and sum up the terms according to a the following formula:

Say you're working in base **x**. Then, if you're at the **i**th position, and that digit is **d**, then that position will contribute a term of **d** times **x^i** to the final sum.

As a concrete example, take your first number - here, **x=7** (the base). Starting from the right, the first digit is **d=6** at the **i=0** position. So we start with **6*(7^0) = 6(1) = 6**.

Moving to the left, **i=1** and **d=5**. So we get **5(7^1) = 5(7) = 35** for this term.

Then, moving to the last digit, **i=2** and **d=4**. So we get **4*(7^2)=4(49)=196** for the last term.

Now, you can just add all of these up to get **35 + 6 + 196 = 237** as your final number (in base 10, that is).

The exact same algorithm works for any base, so you should be able to apply it to the binary number in the exact same way.

(Just let **x=2** and work right to left, noting that **i** ranges from 0 to 7 here.)